# Postgres Completely Ignores Configurations set in postgresql.conf file

Tags: postgresql, configuration

Everytime I startup the server it seems to completely ignore all configuration settings. My data directory is an external drive, so I use `pg_ctl -D /Volumes/Data/Postgres start` to start.

It only accepts localhost connections on port 5432, which I have confirmed by `show listen_addresses;` even though the config file has the following under connection settings:

```
#listen_addresses = '*' # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 9000                # (change requires restart)
```

I also checked the postgresql.auto.conf file, as apparently this overrides the config file, and its completely empty.

For the record the database has crashed a few times due to power being disconnected/connection issues...but it still works fine it seems because I can connect locally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to remove the `#` in the beginning of the configuration file line. PostgreSQL ignores everything from `#` to the end of the line.

Most of the `postgresql.conf` entries are “commented out” in that fashion. This should serve as documentation: you can see what parameters there are and what the default value is.